# Use sed to replace all occurrences of strings which start with 'xy' and of length 5 or more

Tags: unix, sed, aix

I am running AIX 6.1

I have a file which contains strings/words starting with some specific characters, say 'xy' or 'Xy' or 'Xy' or 'XY' (case insensitive) and I need to mask the entire word/string with asterisks '*' if the word is greater than say 5 characters.

e.g. I need a sed command which when run against a file containing the below line...

```
This is a test line  xy12345  xy12  Xy123 Xy11111 which I need to replace specific strings
```

should give below as the output

```
This is a test line xy12 which I need to replace specific strings
```

I tried the below commands (did not yet come to the stage where I restrict to word lengths) but it does not work and displays the full line without any substitutions.

I tried using \< and > as well as \b for word identification.

```
sed 's/\<xy\(.*\)\>/******/g' result2.csv
sed 's/\bxy\(.*\)\b******/g' result2.csv
```

Comment: If your `sed` is not GNU `sed`, you should consider using some other tool.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can use any other command as well. Please suggest. I am not sure if my sed is GNU sed or not.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51042212/3832970) with an online demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with awk:

```
echo 'This is a test line  xy12345  xy12  Xy123 Xy11111 which I need to replace specific strings' | awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} !(/^[xX][yY]/ && length($0)>=5)'
```

The awk record separator is set to a space in order to be able to get the length of each word.

This works with GNU awk in `--posix` and `--traditional` modes.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It is helpful.

However...
1. It removes the words with start with xy/Xy etc. and does not replace them with *
2. Also the delimited between words can be space, comma and it can even be the very first or last word in each line.

Comment: @Sora This script outputs the same string as in your question. If you have other requirements, please update your question with an example containing all different cases.

Answer (score 1):

With sed for the mental exercice

```
sed -E '
  s/(^|[[:blank:]])([xyXY])([xyXY].{2}[^[:space:]]*)([^[:space:]])/\1@\3@/g
  :A
  s/(@[^@[:blank:]]*)[^@[:blank:]](@[@]*)/\1@\2/g
  tA
  s/@/*/g'
```

This need to not have @ in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `awk`:

```
s='This is a test line  xy12345  xy12  Xy123 Xy11111 which I need to replace specific strings xy123 xy1234 xy12345 xy123456 xy1234567'
echo "$s" | awk 'BEGIN {
    ORS=RS=" "
} 
{ 
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if(length($i) >= 5 && $i~/^[Xx][Yy][a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) 
            gsub(/./,"*", $i);
            print $i;
    } 
}'
```

A one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=RS=" "} { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if(length($i) >= 5 && $i~/^[Xx][Yy][a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) gsub(/./,"*", $i); print $i; } }'
# => This is a test line ******* xy12 ***** ******* which I need to replace specific strings ***** ****** ******* ******** *********
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nTLzNt).

**Details**

- `BEGIN {ORS=RS=" "}` - start of the `awk`: set the output record separator equal to the space record separator
- `{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if(length($i) >= 5 && $i~/^xy[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) gsub(/./,"*", $i); print $i; } }` - iterate over each field (with `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)`) and if the current field (`$i`) length is equal or more than 5 (`length($i) >= 5`) and it matches a `Xy` and (`&&`) 1 or more alphanumeric chars pattern (`$i~/^[Xx][Yy][a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`), then replace each char with `*` (with `gsub(/./,"*", $i)`) and then print the current field value.

Comment: @kvantour Well, turning `xy` into `[Xx][Yy]` is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple POSIX `awk` version :

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i ~ /^[xX][yY]/ && length($i)>=5) gsub(/./,"*",$i)}1'
```

This, however, does not keep the spacing intact (multiple spaces are converted to a single one), the following does:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "}(/^[xX][yY]/ && length($i)>=5){gsub(/./,"*")}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/\bxy\S{5,}\b/I!b;s//\n&\n/;h;s/[^\n]/*/g;H;g;s/\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/;ta' file
```

If the current line does not contain a string which begins with `xy` case insensitive and 5 or more following characters, then there is no work to be done.

Otherwise:

1. Surround the string by newlines
2. Copy the pattern space (PS) to the hold space (HS)
3. Replace all characters other than newlines with `*`'s
4. Append the PS to the HS
5. Replace the PS with the HS
6. Swap the strings between the newlines retaining the remainder of the first line
7. Repeat